# SELECT * FROM USERS but not me

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I store users with ids. How to get all the users, except mine? I guess I'll need something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USERS 
EXCEPT WHERE iduser = myiduser
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE iduser != myiduser ;
```

or this:

```
    SELECT * FROM USERS 
    except
    select * from users
    WHERE iduser = myiduser ;
```

or you can create a view

```
Create View Everyone_else
as
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE iduser != myiduser ;
```

then call it with

```
Select * from Everyone_else ;
```

you might have to use apostrophes for myiduser, like this: `'myiduser'`

Comment: @James EXCEPT is like UNION in that it's followed by a new query which returns the same columns as the query above it. It removes records from the result set of the first query. It can be an elegant way of applying complex conditions, but I can't say I use it often.

Comment: I've always used '<>' for "not equal" rather than '!='. Has sql-server added support for the more programmer-friendly syntax?

Comment: '<>' is standard, but several vendors allow '! =' as well.